# JOOQ: how to fetch records grouped by field?

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I need to get map `Map<String, List<Message>>` using JOOQ. I write on Kotlin. I need to group messages by usernames. My code begins at:

```
fun getAllForUsernames(usernames: List<String>): Map<String, List<Message>> =
        dsl.selectFrom(Messages.MESSAGES)
            .where(Messages.MESSAGES.USERNAME.`in`(usernames))
            // ??? returns Map<String, List<Message>>
```

Please, suggest, how to finish function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the out-of-the-box mapping functions, namely [`ResultQuery.fetchGroups(Field, Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchGroups(org.jooq.Field,java.lang.Class))

```kotlin
dsl.selectFrom(MESSAGES)
   .where(MESSAGES.USERNAME.`in`(usernames))
   .fetchGroups(MESSAGES.USERNAME, Message::class.java)
```